# Round Robin Scheduling with Quantum and Produce Table

Tags: java

I want to make a round robin scheduling. I already set the number quantum = 2. It will generate the 'time' and 'extra'

time and extra are depending from Burst Time. Quantum = 2. Burst Time = 10. so, time is 2 and extra is 8. If Burst time = 1, then time is 1, extra is 0. If burst time = 2, then time = 2, extra = 0.

Here is my works, Im kinda stuck over there. Idk how to make generate for time and extra.

[image: Figure 1: Table Should Produce Like This]

```
package roundrobinscheduling;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RoundRobinScheduling {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfProcess = 0;
    int quantum = 2;

    System.out.print("Number of Process: ");
    noOfProcess = input.nextInt();

    int[] burstTime = new int[noOfProcess];
    int[] priority = new int[noOfProcess];
    String[] process = new String[noOfProcess];
    int[] waitingTime = new int[noOfProcess];

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcess; i++) {
        System.out.print("Name Process: ");
        process[i] = input.next();

        System.out.print("Burst Time: ");
        burstTime[i] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Priority: ");
        priority[i] = input.nextInt();
    }

    int[] temp = new int[0];
    for (int k = 0; k < noOfProcess; k++) {

    }

    int[] baki = new int[0];
    int bakitemp = 0;
    System.out.println("|--Process--|--Burst Time--|--Priority--|--Time--|--Extra--|");

    for (int j = 0; j < noOfProcess; j++) {

        if (burstTime[j] == quantum) {
            baki[j] = bakitemp;
            time[j] = burstTime[j];

        } else if (burstTime[j] > quantum) {
            //burstTime[j] = burstTime[j] - quantum;
            baki[j] = burstTime[j] - quantum;
            time[j] = quantum;
        } else {
            baki[j] = bakitemp;
            time[j] = burstTime[j];

        }

        if (j > 0) {
            waitingTime[j] = waitingTime[j - 1] + burstTime[j-1];
        }

        System.out.println("|     " + process[j] + "     |       " + burstTime[j] + "      |   " + priority[j] + "        |    " + time[j] + "   |   " + baki[j] + "    |     " + "  A   " + waitingTime[j]);

    }

}}
```

---

NEW TASK:
I have an assignment that I need to submit by this Sunday. If you want the full questions, its okay. But I want to figure it out one by one if I can make it. *"If the user enters a valid account number and the correct PIN for that
account, the screen displays the main menu. If the user enters an invalid
account number or an incorrect PIN, the screen displays an appropriate
message, then the ATM returns to Step 1 to restart the authentication
process.
"* 
So, how to make arrays store the account number and pin number in system. When we input the account number and pin number correct as we save, we can proceed. I want to make at least 3 account Numbers. I hope you don't mind to help me.

**Account class:**  Add this in the same package as your other ATM class

```
class Account {

    private final int accountNumber;        // A 5 digit number
    private final int pinNumber;            // A 5 digit number
    private final String accountName;       // The first Name
    private double accountBalance;  // The money in the account

    public Account(int accountNumber, int pinNumber, String accountName) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.pinNumber = pinNumber;
        this.accountName = accountName;
        accountBalance = 0.0;
    }

    public double getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(double accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public int getPinNumber() {
        return pinNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void debitAccount(double amount) {
        accountBalance -= amount;
    }

    public void creditAccount(double amount) {
        accountBalance += amount;
    }

}
```

**AccountService class:**

```
class AccountService {
Account[] accounts;

public AccountService() {
    accounts = new Account[3];
    accounts[0] = new Account(12345, 123, "Eisom");
    accounts[1] = new Account(98765, 321, "Hazman");
    accounts[2] = new Account(14123, 456, "Aina");
    accounts[0].setAccountBalance(800.00);
    accounts[1].setAccountBalance(650.00);
    accounts[2].setAccountBalance(500.00);
}

public boolean isValidAccount(int accountNumber, int pinNumber) {

    for (int j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
        if ((accountNumber == accounts[j].getAccountNumber()) && (pinNumber == accounts[j].getPinNumber())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public Account getAccount(int accountNumber, int pinNumber) {

    for (int j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
        if ((accountNumber == accounts[j].getAccountNumber()) && (pinNumber == accounts[j].getPinNumber())) {
            return accounts[j];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Now you have to use AccountService class in your ATM program:**

```
// Now the ATM has an account
private Account account;

// The service to lookup the account based on account number and pin
AccountService service = new AccountService();

// New loop using account service
while (true) {
    MenuDisplay();
    InputAccountNumber();

    boolean isValid = service.isValidAccount(accountNumber, pinNumber);
    if (isValid) {
        account = service.getAccount(accountNumber, pinNumber);
        Menu();
    } else
        System.out.println("Wrong Account Number/PIN Number. Please Try Again.");
}
```

Now the rest of your code has to use `account`.  The account getters and setters get access to the person's name, balance.
Example:

```
public void BalanceEnquiries() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-------BALANCE ENQUIRIES-------");
    System.out.println("User Account Balance: RM" + account.getAccountBalance());
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Proceeding back to Main Menu...");
    System.out.println("");

}
```

Let me know if this makes sense so far.

Here is the Withdrawal example:

```
public void attemptWithdrawal(double amount) {

    if (account.getAccountBalance() < amount) {
        System.out.println("Not Insuffient...");
        System.out.println("You put exceed from your account balance. Please try again");
        System.out.println("Please put lower amount.");
        return;
    }

    System.out.printf("Withdrawal RM%.2f?\n", amount);
    moneyAfterWithdrawal = account.getAccountBalance()-amount;
    System.out.printf("psst: your remaining account will be RM%.2f\n", moneyAfterWithdrawal);
    System.out.println("[Y]Yes   [N]No");
    confirmWithdrawal = input.next().charAt(0);

    if ((confirmWithdrawal == 'Y') || (confirmWithdrawal == 'y')) {
        System.out.println("Congrate! You successfully withdrawal the money");
        realMoney -= moneyAfterWithdrawal;
        account.debitAccount(amount);  // Take the money out
    } else if ((confirmWithdrawal == 'N') || (confirmWithdrawal == 'n')) {
        // Going back to this method
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Proceeding to Others again...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Wrong Character...");
    }

}

public void Withdrawal() {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-------WITHDRAWAL-------");
    System.out.println(" [1]RM50.00   [2]RM100.00");
    System.out.println(" [3]Others    [4]Exit");
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.print("Enter the Code: ");
    chooseOptionWithdrawalString = input.next();
    chooseOptionWithdrawal = Integer.parseInt(chooseOptionWithdrawalString);

    switch (chooseOptionWithdrawal) {
    case 1:
        attemptWithdrawal(50.0);
        break;
    case 2:
        attemptWithdrawal(100.0);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("How many money you want to withdrawal: ");
        moneyWithdrawal = input.nextDouble();
        attemptWithdrawal(moneyWithdrawal);
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You enter wrong input. Please try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Notes:**
1.  Account number and pin number.

a)  It would be easier to work with Strings.  But ints are fine.
b)  The PIN number must be 5 digits (your are using 3)
c)  The account number 100000 is currently allowed (but shouldn't be it is 6 digits)
d)  Otherwise this section is good!

2. Withdraw:

a)  It will help you a lot if you create a new method like `attemptWithdraw(double amount)`.  You have a lot of repetitive code (like $50, $100, and when user chooses other amount).  No matter if the user wants 50, 100 or 200, the exact same method should be called  (attemptWithdraw).  In this method you can: 
a)  Make sure the user has enough money (warn them if they don't)
b)  Make sure the ATM has enough money (warn them if the ATM doesn't)
c)  Debit / reduce the persons account by `amount` (if a and b are good)
d)  Remind the user to take the money

Once you create this extra method, then call it for 50, 100, and other.  You will find it easier because you write the same code only once.

3. Deposit

a) I don't think you check for 0 to exit.
b) The person's balance doesn't get debited, because you use a new variable moneyAfterDeposit.  You need to use `accountBalanceTemp` like you do for `realMoney`.
c)  I think you need to tell them to insert a deposit slip.
d)  There is a two minute timer; if they don't you must abort the transaction.

I'll stop there.  You have lots of good code.  Just a few more changes and you will be there.

Comment: Do you have to process all of the processes until burst time = 0 for all of them?  For example P1 has burst time = 10.  Each iteration of P1 will reduce by quantum=2; 10 -> 8 -> 6 -> 4 -> 2 -> 0.  Do you have to display each step (i.e. round robin)?  Does priority mean anything?  Is burst sorted first before processing?

Comment: yes.. ignore the table, i think my table is wrong. but the idea is like that. priority is nothing. just ignore priority. burst is not sorted but we have to by process p1 until p5 .

Comment: Does waiting time still need to be calculated?

Comment: yes. and it still start with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performs round robin scheduling without any initial priority (i.e. A, then B).  Processing continues until all processes have no burst remaining.

```
public class RoundRobinScheduling {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfProcess = 0;
    int quantum = 2;

    System.out.print("Number of Process: ");
    noOfProcess = input.nextInt();

    int[] burstTime = new int[noOfProcess];
    int[] priority = new int[noOfProcess];
    String[] process = new String[noOfProcess];
    int waitingTime = 0;

    int processesComplete = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcess; i++) {
        System.out.print("Name Process: ");
        process[i] = input.next();

        System.out.print("Burst Time: ");
        burstTime[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (burstTime[i] == 0)
            processesComplete++;

        System.out.print("Priority: ");
        priority[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();

    int roundRobinIndex = 0;

    System.out.println(" | Process | CPU Burst | Priority | Time  |  Waiting Time | ");
    while (processesComplete < noOfProcess) {
        if (burstTime[roundRobinIndex] > 0) {
            // Here we want to subtract the full quantum (2)
            // But what if burst time left = 1?  Then we can't subtract 2
            // Math.min takes 2 arguments, and returns the smaller of the two
            // Math.min(2, 1) = 1
            // Math.min(2, 2) = 2
            // Math.min(2, 3) = 2
            int time = Math.min(quantum, burstTime[roundRobinIndex]);
            burstTime[roundRobinIndex] -= time;
            // Determine if this process has finished
            // It is finished when bursttime has reduced to zero
            // processComplete = processComplete + 1
            if (burstTime[roundRobinIndex] == 0)
                processesComplete++;

            System.out.println(" |    " + process[roundRobinIndex] + "    |    " + burstTime[roundRobinIndex]
                    + "      |    " + priority[roundRobinIndex] + "     |    " + time + "  |     " + waitingTime
                    + "        | ");
            // waitingTime += time;
            waitingTime += quantum;  // I think this is correct (CPU will take full quantum each time

        }
        roundRobinIndex = (roundRobinIndex + 1) % noOfProcess;
    }

}
}
```

For the data provided (processes A-E), produces the following result.

```
| Process | CPU Burst | Priority | Time  |  Waiting Time | 
|    A    |    8      |    3     |    2  |     0        | 
|    B    |    0      |    1     |    1  |     2        | 
|    C    |    0      |    3     |    2  |     4        | 
|    D    |    0      |    4     |    1  |     6        | 
|    E    |    3      |    2     |    2  |     8        | 
|    A    |    6      |    3     |    2  |     10        | 
|    E    |    1      |    2     |    2  |     12        | 
|    A    |    4      |    3     |    2  |     14        | 
|    E    |    0      |    2     |    1  |     16        | 
|    A    |    2      |    3     |    2  |     18        | 
|    A    |    0      |    3     |    2  |     20        |
```

EDIT:  Here is the fix for Round:

```
public class Round {

int process = 0;
// DON'T create the array yet!
// You don't know how big to make it (yet).
// Until you ask how many processes there are
int[] processvalue;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Round r = new Round();
    r.input();
    r.loop();
    r.print();
}

void input() {

    System.out.print("how many process");
//      n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    process = sc.nextInt();
    // HERE is where you now must create the array
    // Now that you know how large to make it 
    processvalue = new int[process];
}

void loop() {

    for (int i = 0; i < process; i++) {
        System.out.println("please input the process " + (i + 1));
        processvalue[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

void print() {

    for (int k = 0; k < process; k++) {
        System.out.println("value" + processvalue[k]);
    }

}

}
```

### EDIT for correct wait time

```
public class RoundRobinScheduling {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int noOfProcess = 0;
    int quantum = 2;

    System.out.print("Number of Process: ");
    noOfProcess = input.nextInt();

    int[] burstTime = new int[noOfProcess];
    int[] priority = new int[noOfProcess];
    String[] process = new String[noOfProcess];
    int[] nextTime = new int[noOfProcess];
    int clockTime = 0;
    double totalWaitTime = 0;

    int processesComplete = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcess; i++) {
        System.out.print("Name Process: ");
        process[i] = input.next();

        System.out.print("Burst Time: ");
        burstTime[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (burstTime[i] == 0)
            processesComplete++;

        System.out.print("Priority: ");
        priority[i] = input.nextInt();
        nextTime[i] = 0;
    }
    input.close();

    int roundRobinIndex = 0;

    System.out.println(" | Process | CPU Burst | Priority | Time  |  Clock Time |  Wait Time |");
    while (processesComplete < noOfProcess) {
        if (burstTime[roundRobinIndex] > 0) {
            int time = Math.min(quantum, burstTime[roundRobinIndex]);
            burstTime[roundRobinIndex] -= time;
            if (burstTime[roundRobinIndex] == 0)
                processesComplete++;
            int waitTime = clockTime - nextTime[roundRobinIndex];
            totalWaitTime += waitTime;

            System.out.println(" |    " + process[roundRobinIndex] + "    |    " + burstTime[roundRobinIndex]
                    + "      |    " + priority[roundRobinIndex] + "     |    " + time + "  |     " + clockTime
                    + "        | " + waitTime + "   |");
            //clockTime += quantum;
            clockTime += time;
            nextTime[roundRobinIndex] = clockTime;
        }
        roundRobinIndex = (roundRobinIndex + 1) % noOfProcess;
    }
    System.out.println("Average wait time="+totalWaitTime/noOfProcess);

}
}
```

Creates the output

```
 | Process | CPU Burst | Priority | Time  |  Clock Time |  Wait Time |
 |    A    |    8      |    3     |    2  |     0        | 0   |
 |    B    |    0      |    1     |    1  |     2        | 2   |
 |    C    |    0      |    3     |    2  |     3        | 3   |
 |    D    |    0      |    4     |    1  |     5        | 5   |
 |    E    |    3      |    2     |    2  |     6        | 6   |
 |    A    |    6      |    3     |    2  |     8        | 6   |
 |    E    |    1      |    2     |    2  |     10        | 2   |
 |    A    |    4      |    3     |    2  |     12        | 2   |
 |    E    |    0      |    2     |    1  |     14        | 2   |
 |    A    |    2      |    3     |    2  |     15        | 1   |
 |    A    |    0      |    3     |    2  |     17        | 0   |
Average wait time=5.8
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected output should look like.  Does this seem close?

Comment: yes it is! I still dont understand the coding that u made. such as math.min.. and processComplete++

Comment: Since I cant create new question because it has the same/related question. I want to ask about this problem. It does not related to this question either and it already solved. I already put the input, but there is no output. [link]https://pastebin.com/j4QAYv42

Comment: I have added a few comments into the program to help explain things a bit.  Also posted the Round class with the fixes, and added comments to hopefully explain why it now works.

Comment: thank you @Ian Mc. how to make total average for waiting time? [link](https://i.imgur.com/djgmmSi.jpg) and then divided by number of process.

Comment: The link says average wait = 3.0 (which is 15 / 5) or (waitingTime / noOfProcess). Should it not be 17/5=3.4? Why is the last wait time 17 not included in the red rectangle?

Comment: Maybe you already fixed the code?  But now the average wait time makes sense to me.  The code has been fixed and edited above in the answer.  The total wait time is 29 (sum of wait time) and 5 processes => 29/5=5.8.

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236055/why-is-this-scanner-assigning-null-to-a-variable/49236184?noredirect=1#comment85475554_49236184 Look at this. I wanted to help him. then I got negative. whats wrong with the community.? :(

Comment: Seriously @Ian Mc, I feel so sad right now because of their reply. I really wanted to help him man... :(

Comment: I am sorry about that situation (I don't see your answer anymore). There are some mean people on this site. This is only a website. In real life you are the better person by far so please try to feel better.

Comment: Hi @Ian Mc, they already removed the post. btw I already updated this thread. I have an assignment. Can you take a look. ps: "NEW TASK"

Comment: I see the new task.  If you want to use arrays, you can create two `String[]` arrays - the size depends on how many accounts you want to hold.  One array name could be accounts.  The other pins.  Then you set `accounts[0] = "someacctno1", and pins[0] = "somepin", and so on.  Then you ask user for account and pin, and loop through each account to see if a match occurs.  I will check often - if you get stuck just ask.  Perhaps add your code so far into the questions, and I'll keep helping.

Comment: can I contact you like skype or anything? or it is ok in here? I already updated with my code.

Comment: I don't mind checking here.  I will add some comments above in the question.

Comment: done.. there is suppose we compare the input console with the system.

Comment: It is full assignment. I think I just finished like 90%. I think a lot of errors. logic error. and I have the question. would you like to see the question?

Comment: Ok sure. I put it in pastebin. [code](https://pastebin.com/ECM27CS2) . [question](https://pastebin.com/Pi4Sr9ge)

Comment: I have added some notes in the question.  You are close - just a few ideas/suggestions.  I'll check again tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thanks... I'm kinda blurr what you were talking about. But I will try to manage as I can. Btw, is that possible to make many classes(.java). Because I have to apply something like aggregation, assiociation.

Comment: Yes, classes are a great idea!  The most important is an Account class.  This would hold everything about an account; name, account number and pin, balance, etc.  Another good class would be an AccountService class.  This would hold all the Accounts (i.e. 3 of them) and methods like `findAccount` and `validateAccount`.  Currently your ATM class has too much code and should be broken down into simpler classes

Comment: yes, but the problem is, I'm not expert doing inheritance and so on. I just know the one that I gave it to you. and btw, what do you mean by 'hold all' ?

Comment: I can post an Account class, and show a few things ... would you prefer I write a bit of the code?

Comment: sure if you dont mind. I was expect I have to finish by Friday, because we need to do some Software Process. there will be for testing, maintenance, enhancement.I don't know if I can make it or not.

Comment: I've posted an Account class which contains the person's information.  And an AccountService class which is used to look up an account.  And ways to use these in the program.  If you understand so far I'll keep going.

Comment: I got some errors at the 'TestATMApplication.java' (where the main void there). and I'm kinda stuck.. I changed the code as you prefer, something happened. I think I put in the wrong section or sort of. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Can you post your latest code? Do you prefer the new classes?

Comment: Maybe should be `ATM.MenuDisplay();`?  Is it errors like this?

Comment: [code](https://pastebin.com/y5cLwYpV) [error picture](https://imgur.com/a/pdFzP) . yeah.. wrong at the test main.

Comment: I see what is wrong.  `Account account`, and `AccountService` belong in the `ATMApplication` class.  Then you need `ATM.validate()` and this method uses `service`.  And it is `ATM.Menu()`

Comment: ohh.. what if we make new class for them? include like own 'Withdrawal.java' , 'Deposit.java' , 'BalanceEnquiries.java'. Is that possible? Make many classes. Then, just let 'ATMApplication.java' will become the MainMenu to call others classes. 'TestATMApplication.java' will become the output.

Comment: Personally I would keep them in the ATM class because they represent ATM functions.  But it is not wrong if you want to make more classes.

Comment: We should get your current code working, and decide to make more classes once you have working code (in case you run out of time)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167775/discussion-between-zuhrain-and-ian-mc).

Comment: Only deposit left . And i try to make full excetion

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: about this one 'case 4:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Have a good day. :)");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("===========================================");
                break;' 
how to make it 'build successfully'.?

Comment: Do you want to chat?

Comment: sure. going to chat. if you are not busy

Comment: My pleasure.  I hope you do very well on your assignment.  You can test more, but I think it is very good code right now.  All the best.